# Foundation 5 Top Bar Doesnt Drop Down

Tags: drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

already read so many topics about this but nothing seems to be working.

just started a project and ive virtually copy/pasted the code from the foundation docs site and it doesnt work.

heres my html
    
    
      
      Test

```
<body>
   <header>              

      <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
         <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
            </li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
         </ul>

        <section class="top-bar-section">
          <!-- Right Nav Section -->
          <ul class="right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
            <li class="has-dropdown">
               <a href="#">Right Button with Dropdown</a>
               <ul class="dropdown">
               <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>

         <!-- Left Nav Section -->
         <ul class="left">
            <li><a href="#">Left Nav Button</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
      </nav>

   </header>

   <footer>
      <p>Some copyright and legal notices here. Maybe use the © symbol a bit.</p>
   </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

for the style sheet, its empty, even tried removing it entirely just to be certain but same thing, its dot dropping down.

any ideas what i missed?
Thanks

EDIT:

ok so found something, the code displayed on zurbs foundation docs page, doesnt work when copy/pasting, however if i use the inspector and copy the html from their example, it works. however when you shrink the browser small, the 3 lines with menu button appears but when hovering over it, it dont drop down, clicking as well does nothing, how to fix that?

the html for that is

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="">
      <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
          <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
        </li>
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="">Menu</a></li>
      </ul>

    <section class="top-bar-section" style="left: 0%;">

        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="right show-for-large-up">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
          <li class="has-dropdown not-click">
            <a href="#">Right Button Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropdown"><li class="title back js-generated"><h5><a     href="javascript:void(0)">Back</a></h5></li>
              <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </section></nav>
```

im loading these scripts

```
  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  <!-- Foundation Top Bar -->
  <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.js"></script>
```

i have also tried removing the topbar and offcanvas scripts and just using the foundation.min.js one, nothing works, button appears but no drop down is available.

Comment: ok so found something, the code displayed on zurbs foundation docs page, doesnt work when copy/pasting, however if i use the inspector and copy the html from their example, it works. however when you shrink the browser small, the 3 lines with menu button appears but when hovering over it, it dont drop down, clicking as well does nothing, how to fix that?

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem today and by doing the same as you did I figured out it's the "not-click" in this line:

```
<li class="has-dropdown not-click">
```

I added it and now it work's just fine (for me (only?)).

Comment: .not-click is added by the JS and should not be added manually

Comment: Using Foundation 5 and I wanted to use the topbar styling, I removed `data-topbar` and added this class to the dropdowns and everything worked properly

Answer (score 6):

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Did not make it work but the following did

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).foundation();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably have found your answer to this question right now but you probably need to add the code below to initialize Foundation when the document is ready.

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use the minimized version of foundation (foundation.min.js) do not load other plugins, because they are loaded automatically , and it will work .

Comment: im not using the minified version im using the normal foundation.js found in the js/foundation folder (js/foundation/foundation.js)

Answer (score 2):

Foundation 5 templates page at [Foundation HTML Templates](http://foundation.zurb.com/templates.html) shows some examples of topbar navigation (your code is ok), but what's not mentioned is dependencies.

- F5 requires jQuery 2, most cms' (Wordpress) use jQuery 1
- jQuery 2 does not work on IE 8 or less, must use IE 9 or better

Comment: This is the first I'd seen about Foundation requiring JQuery 2.  Very helpful to know.

Comment: Foundation 5 does NOT require Jquery 2

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).foundation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your project working now? You will have to load the following files

```
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What fixed it for me was removing turbolinks:

1. Remove the gem 'turbolinks' line from your Gemfile.
2. Remove the //= require turbolinks from your app/assets/javascripts/application.js.
3. Remove the two "data-turbolinks-track" => true hash key/value pairs from your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.
   (from http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I try to avoid js when [css-only can do the job just fine](https://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/ujHzd).  It keeps the mental model of what Foundation is trying to accomplish for you all the more simple.

It is a simple as HTML code

```
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
```

which only need css declaration classes.